# How to solve infinite loop to show Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, server, user-experience

I'm trying to create my own chat app as a school project.

I have almost everything ready, connected with DB, backend. The only thing that is weighing me down right now is adding a TCP Server to the project for communication between Clients.

It's not supposed to be anything big, so just short code, plus I don't have that much experience with TCP in C#.
The code works, but the problem is that the Application/Window doesn't appear.

I suspected that the problem might be in the `MainWindow()` constructor due to the infinite loop (this was also confirmed here on SO). Unfortunately I don't know how to fix it anymore. I first had the server as a separate class, but I ran into this problem. So I tried implementing it directly in the class, or breaking the connection after shutting down the application.

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window {

    private TcpListener myServer;
    private bool isRunning;

    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      myServer = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 65525);
      myServer.Start();
      isRunning = true;
      LoopServer();
    }

    private void LoopServer() {
      while (isRunning) {
        TcpClient client = myServer.AcceptTcpClient();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(LoopClient));
        thread.Start(client);

      }
    }

    private void LoopClient(object obj) {
      TcpClient client = (TcpClient) obj;
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
      StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
      MessageBox.Show("Connected bro!");
      writer.Flush();
      bool clientRunning = true;
      while (clientRunning) {
        string data = reader.ReadLine();
        MessageBox.Show(data);
        writer.Flush();
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop is okay for a server to be running in.  Generally, you can start up the server (1st application). The clients (different application) can connect to it and then process messages and broadcast them to all the clients appropriately.

Super simple example: [Build Chat in C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server-programming.htm)

Alternatively you can try an event based approach to the TCP listener.

Comment: My friend got great ide, that I should offload the loop to a different thread in the thread pool. `Task.Run {// my loop};`